# Не компилируется JavaFX приложение

Tags: java, javafx

Импортировал библиотеку, но приложение не компилируется. Код исходный, я ничего не менял.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код файла sample.fxml :

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код файла в вопрос, а также traceback(скриншоты не приветствуются на StackOverFlow) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4692/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85

Answer (score 0):

Я не экстрасенс, но смею предположить, что у Вас версия JDK 11+. С версии 11 JavaFX вынесен из стандартной поставки JDK в отдельный пакет. Это раз. Второе, в Java с версии 9 появились модули, и теперь если Вам нужен в Вашем приложении модуль, Вы должны его явно указать либо в строке запуска приложения через параметр --add-modules, либо прописав его в файле module-info.java. В Вашем конкретном случае Вам нужны модули javafx.controls и javafx.fxml. Т.е. к строке запуска приложения добавляем такое

```
--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Либо в файле module-info.java пишем

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
```